# Applescript and iTunes: enable shuffle by song or album and play?

Tags: itunes, applescript, playlist

The documentation for shuffle/shufflable in the iTunes Applescript dictionary is really confusing, at least for me. As I read it shuffle seems to be a property of a playlist (not a state of the program itself) but in the regular UI there is no such property for playlists (I would love to have it so I could set some playlists to always shuffle by album while other should always shuffle by song).

Anyway, I want an Applescript that enables shuffle by song/album and plays the currently selected playlist. How do I write the shuffle part of such a script?

Comment: I'd check out [Doug's Applescripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/). No point re-inventing the wheel. Received wisdom is, if it's not on there, it probably can't be done.

Comment: I have looked there but didn't find anything applicable.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Music"
    set shuffle enabled to true
    set shuffle mode to albums
    play current playlist
end tell
```

https://dougscripts.com/itunes/2016/05/the-return-of-shuffle-and-repeat/